# Running Flask environment using HTML:receiving error message of expected else statement

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am getting an error message as follows:  TemplateSyntaxError: Unexpected end of template. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'elif' or 'else' or 'endif'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'if'.

I am using a Linux environment and this code should calculate interest rates.There are seperate files for running the scripts and the function.However once running the program i am getting an error message at the page stating that theres an expected else statement before the following code:

```
return render_template('interest_form.html', calc_total=True).
```

Below is the full code:

```
from server import app, valid_time
from flask import request, render_template
from Calculator import Calculator


@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def interest_total():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        initial=float(request.form["initial"])
        rate=float(request.form["rate"])
        time=float(request.form["time"])
        Calculator.total_interest(initial,rate,time)
        total=Calculator.total_interest()
        return render_template('interest_form.html', total=total)
    return render_template('interest_form.html', calc_total=True)


@app.route('/time', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def time_interest():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        initial=float(request.form["initial"])
        rate=float(request.form["rate"])
        total=float(request.form["total"])
        Calculator.time_required(initial,rate,total)
        time=Calculator.time_required()
        return render_template('interest_form.html', time=time)
    return render_template('interest_form.html', calc_time=True)



@app.route('/credits', methods=['GET'])
def credits():
    return render_template('credits.html')
```

I am trying using a html form to send the input:

```
<!doctype.html>

<head><h2>Interest</h2><head>
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <form action="routes.py" method='POST'>
         <div style="margin: 10px 0px">
            <label>Amount Invested ($): </label><br/>
            <input  name="initial" placeholder="Amount Invested"/>
        </div>
        <div style="margin: 10px 0px">
            <label>Interest Rate (%): </label><br/>
            <input  name="rate" placeholder="Amount Invested"/>
        </div>
         <div style="margin: 10px 0px">
            <label>Time Investment (Years): </label><br/>
            <input name="time" placeholder="Amount Invested"  {%if calc_time %}disabled{% endif %}/>
        </div>
         <div style="margin: 10px 0px">
            <label>Total Interest ($): </label><br/>
            <input  name="total" placeholder="Amount Invested"  {%if calc_total %}disabled{% endif %}/>
        </div>
            <div style="margin: 10px 0px">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div><p>{{initial}} and {{time}}</p></div>

        {% if total %}<h4>Total amount is<h4>
        <textarea name="Amount" rows="5" cols="20"> {{total}} </textarea>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
<a href="file:///tmp_amd/cage/export/cage/4/project/templates/interest_form.html/time">Time Form</a>
<a href="file:///tmp_amd/cage/export/cage/4/project/templates/interest_form.html">Total Form</a>
<br/><a href="/credits">Credits Page</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used a different template code that has a similar function and return format and when running it there seems to be no problem with it.This,however,seems to be showing the abovementioned error message.

(EDIT:I have updated the following code):

```
                {% if total %}<h4>Total amount is</h4>
                <textarea name="Amount" rows="5" cols="20"> {{total}}</textarea>
                {% endif %}
                </form>
```

Howver the error message is now showing: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Unexpected end of template. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'block'.

Comment: the bad indentation in the line `Calculator.time_required(initial,rate,total)`is just a typo, right?

Comment: Yup it is!Edited!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to close the `if` block in your template:

```
 {% if total %}
        <h4>Total amount is<h4>
        <textarea name="Amount" rows="5" cols="20"> {{total}</textarea>
    </form>
 {% endif %}
```

Updated answer after the edit:

You need also an `{% endblock %}`at the end of the file for closing the `{% block content %}`at the top of the file.

Comment: Hi there.Now the error is showing:       jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Unexpected end of template. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'block'.

Comment: It is now showing error message as said in the edit section of the question above.There seems to be two errors including this now.

Comment: Every `{% block content %}` segment must be closed with a  `{% endblock %}`.  Add one at the end.  Also, why are you putting an ENTIRE web page into the block?  Is your `base.html` empty?  `base.html` should (in most cases) be a complete html document, into which you insert content using  `{% block ... %}...{% endblock %}`

Comment: @GAEfan Thanks!!Just realized the problem.As for the base.html,Its suppose to just contain the header title for the file as part of the specifications.

Comment: @Harris, answer updated after your edit. If it solved your problem, feel free to accept it : )

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar error - cause was a `{% block content %}` which I thought would not be affecting as it was commented out in HTML - turns out it was the culprit.

details:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Unexpected end of template. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'.The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'block'.

I know that each `{% block content %}` needs an `{% endblock %}` but what I didn't know was that if you have HTML comments around a `{% block content %}` , it doesn't work(i.e. it doesn't really get commented)

just putting it here in case anyone struggles the way I did for long before figuring it out.
below in my html code, although this was commented, it was the culprit that was giving me that exception.
`

```
<!-- 
 {% block content %}
<table>
    <tr valign='top'>
        <td> <img src="{{ user.avatar(128) }}"></td>
 -->
```

removing the `{% block content %}` from commented code solved it.

Comment: Thank you for this, I was going crazy. I couldn't find this mentioned anywhere but here

Answer (score 0):

My half a day gone just breaking my head around it. Such a sad state, Jinja really sucks...the message was not clear, I literally had to run through the entire code to check for matching if/for what else... Now I removed all the comments from the page and it worked.. There were no blocks inside such comments..even then it worked... Angry with Jinja...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30717078)