# Unexpected end of template. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'block'

Tags: python, jinja2

I have visited these answers too [Running Flask environment using HTML:receiving error message of expected else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822676/running-flask-environment-using-htmlreceiving-error-message-of-expected-else-st) and [How to fix jinja2 exceptions Template SyntaxError:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933020/how-to-fix-jinja2-exceptions-template-syntaxerror) but could not solve the problem.

I am a beginner at Flask and tried using jinja2 template inheritance. Here are my files.

**index.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}

        <!-- Page Header-->
        <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('{{ url_for('static',filename='assets/img/home-bg.jpg') }}')">
            <div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <div class="site-heading">
                            <h1>Clean Blog</h1>
                            <span class="subheading">A Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Main Content-->
        <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
            <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                    <!-- Divider-->
                    <hr class="my-4" />
                    <!-- Pager-->
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-4"><a class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" href="#!">Older Posts →</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

{% endblock body %}
```

**layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <link href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Navigation-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="/about">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

{% block body %} { % endblock % }

    <!-- Footer-->
        <footer class="border-top">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <ul class="list-inline text-center">
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="#!">
                                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I want to inheritent the template from **layout.html** to **index.html**. But I am getting this error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Unexpected end of template. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'block'.
```

I have surfed a lot of websites to solve it but could not. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! I just got the reason for the error. The error was generated at this line:

```
{% block body %} { % endblock % }
```

After figuring it out, I came to know that there should be no space between the braces and the `%` sign. And the code should look like this.

```
{% block body %} {% endblock %}
```